# Angular ng-select multi select checkbox

Tags: html, angular

Is you see the examle so what i want is when i click on top FEMALE this need to check all box the same now, but i dont want the name inside the input  ho i can do? Thanks

Here is the example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rspagz

https://dgf1hw.run.stackblitz.io/

```
<ng-select
    [items]="people"
    [multiple]="true"
    bindLabel="name"
    groupBy="gender"
    [selectableGroup]="true"
    [selectableGroupAsModel]="true"
    [closeOnSelect]="false"
    bindValue="id"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedPeople">
    <ng-template ng-optgroup-tmp let-item="item" let-item$="item$" let-index="index">
        <input id="item-{{index}}" type="checkbox" (click)="test(item.gender)" [ngModel]="item$.selected" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone : true }"/> {{item.gender | uppercase}}
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-item$="item$" let-index="index">
        <input id="item-{{index}}" type="checkbox" [ngModel]="item$.selected"/> {{item.name}}
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

Comment: the stackblitz is not working. can you share a new link?

Comment: try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rspagz

Comment: you don't want to show the name of the persons or you don't want to show the female keyword?

Comment: after click on Female, i dont want to shot the name Female on input, because i need to create type accordion so when i clcik n FEmale hide the under list